# Background image fills Raphael SVG to Canvas via canvg are black

Tags: svg, raphael

I have found the info on converting a raphael SVG into a canvas element here very helpful. But I'm a little stuck - I have a Raphael SVG drawn (it's a little ugly, sorry, but it works), and I can almost recreate it on canvas via canvg, except my fill patterns are all black. Is there something wrong in the SVG code rendered?

Here is an example of the svg code (innerHTML) of my raphael drawing:

```
<svg height="530" version="1.1" width="530" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: relative; "><desc>Created with Raphaël 2.0.0</desc><defs><pattern id="BDC4C7DB-1FF9-4BE5-B868-C7B68C6A7B8B" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1" patternTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(535.9612108001184,76)"><image x="0" y="0" href="assets/img/crush_gloss/coral_bell_gloss.jpg"></image></pattern><pattern id="75CC740F-C521-4E46-BE6F-2CE15E4CD6D4" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1" patternTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(-31.03878919988169,426)"><image x="0" y="0" href="assets/img/crush_gloss/coral_bell_gloss.jpg"></image></pattern><pattern id="70CBF480-046A-4F7D-8B41-FD642EC8109B" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1" patternTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(265.9612108001183,76)"><image x="0" y="0" href="assets/img/crush_gloss/habenero_gloss.jpg"></image></pattern><pattern id="146B2DC3-E4B5-4959-BFCD-6A6CF69E3300" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1" patternTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0) translate(238.96121080011827,26)"><image x="0" y="0" href="assets/img/crush_gloss/coral_bell_gloss.jpg"></image></pattern> ... AND ON ... </defs></svg>
```

I am using the following to try to recreate my SVG in canvas:

```
innerSVG=document.getElementById('app_display').innerHTML;
//alert (innerSVG);
// load svg snippet in the canvas  
canvg('canv', innerSVG);
```

My patterns draw fine, my background fill color is fine, it's just the image fill on the patterns I've drawn that's not okay; they're always black. I have tried referencing them by full url, relative, it makes no difference. There is no base meta tag on this page. Thoughts on where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `href` with `xlink:href`

```
<image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="assets/img/crush_gloss/coral_bell_gloss.jpg"></image>
```

Or...

```
canvg('canv', innerSVG.replace("href","xlink:href"));
```

Comment: i was hoping that would be it - i noticed some issues people reported of xlink:href= being the correct specification. but that didn't work for me. i still show my great patterns, but black fill. :-/ still digging.

Comment: i've made a demo of what i'm doing, first the svg drawn (just one circle with an image fill), then trying to convert to canvas (so i have a png i can do something with) - i just can't seem to get the image fill to work. http://dev.fireclaytile.com/crush-it/simple.html

Comment: Even if you copy the string and reduce it to it's minimal valid expression it still doesn't display the image, so I suspect a bug in canvg. I see that you are using the development version of canvg (trunk), perhaps try replacing it with an older version.